# Custom Permalink for Archive URL strucutre

Tags: wordpress, customization

I want to have a custom URL structure for Date/Year Archive.

Currently wordpress CMS provides the structure as

```
http://wordpress.com/2012/04/13/
```

for the calendar URL structure, but I want to do it as

```
http://wordpress.com/**archive**/2012/04/13/
```

only for calender URL structure only but not for single post.

Please guide me how to do it.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can find an explenation about how to rewrite the permalinks [here](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/the-rewrite-api-post-types-taxonomies/)